# How to write a pandas df into Excel using Python xlwings with skip_blanks enabled?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, xlwings

My python script generates a pandas dataframe containing some NaN values:

```
       A         B         C         D
0.351741  NaN       0.238705  NaN     
0.950817  0.665594  0.671151  NaN     
NaN       0.442725  0.658816  NaN     
0.155604  0.567044  NaN       0.666576
NaN       0.751562  NaN       0.597252
0.577770  NaN       NaN       0.123392
```

I want to write this df into an excel spreadsheet using xlwings. The important point is that I need to skip the cells set to NaN and preserve the corresponding excel cells. **In my case, the cells that I want to preserve can contain live excel formula, values or even empty cells.**

If my excel values are:

```
      A         B         C         D
Excel A1  Excel B1  Excel C1  Excel D1 
Excel A2  Excel B2  Excel C2  Excel D2 
Excel A3  Excel B3  Excel C3  Excel D3 
Excel A4  Excel B4  Excel C4  Excel D4
Excel A5  Excel B5  Excel C5  Excel D5
Excel A6  Excel B6  Excel C6  Excel D6
```

The final output should be:

```
       A         B         C         D
0.351741  Excel B1  0.238705  Excel D1
0.950817  0.665594  0.671151  Excel D2
Excel A3  0.442725  0.658816  Excel D3
0.155604  0.567044  Excel C4  0.666576
Excel A5  0.751562  Excel C5  0.597252
0.577770  Excel B6  Excel C6  0.123392
```

Usually, I write to Excel using a simple xlwings call:

```
r = 'A1:D6'
sht.range(r).options(index=False, header=False).value = df
```

With this call, the NaN would overwrite the excel cell by an empty cell. Loosing the values that I want to preserve. In our previous example, it means that I would obtain this in Excel:

```
       A         B         C         D
0.351741  BLANK     0.238705  BLANK   
0.950817  0.665594  0.671151  BLANK   
BLANK     0.442725  0.658816  BLANK   
0.155604  0.567044  BLANK     0.666576
BLANK     0.751562  BLANK     0.597252
0.577770  BLANK     BLANK     0.123392
```

I checked xlwings documentation and its code. It seems that the parameter `skip_blanks` is only implemented for the function `paste()`. It is set to `False` by default. The only workaround that I currently found is to use a temporary sheet where I save my df. Then, I copy to the clipboard the range where it was saved. Finally, I can paste it where I want using `skip_blanks=True` obtaining the expected output:

```
tmp_sht.range(r).options(index=False, header=False).value = df 
tmp_sht.range(r).copy(destination=None)
sht.range(r).paste(paste='values', skip_blanks=True)
```

I don't like to use this temporary sheet. I suppose xlwings should be able to handle a direct call using the `skip_blanks`, something that would look like this:

```
sht.range(r).options(index=False, header=False, skip_blanks=True).value = df
```

Is it possible to do it?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: assuming `df1` and `df2`: `out = df1.combine_first(df2)`

Comment: @mozway, no this is not what I need.
the destination is not available in the python script. It needs to preserve the values or formulas present in the excel file. Please reopen my question.

Comment: you can load your sheet and follow what I linked to, this will work and will be quite easy, other option `stack` your DataFrame and save each cell one by one. Best would be to provide a reproducible excel sheet (or code to generate one)

Comment: It would work if you only want to keep the hardcoded values. 
If you want to preserve some excel formula, this wouldn't work as they would be overwritten by their values.

Comment: a `stack` will work in any case, but you have to save the cells one by one

Comment: @FelixZumstein, could you please check if you can help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way to solve this issue is based on the idea of @mozway to move the whole process to python by retrieving the values we want to preserve and simply combining the two dataframes:

```
out = df1.combine_first(df2)
```

You can retrieve the formulas from the excel file using the `formula` parameter of a `Range`. Depending on the types of your values, you could simply replace the NaN like this:

```
formulas = sht.range(r).options(pd.DataFrame).formula
df = df.fillna(formulas)  # replace the `NaN` with the formulas
```

This actually didn't work for me due to some dtypes that the function `fillna` cannot handle. But I adapted it by changing the index and columns of the retrieved df to be able to use combine_first:

```
formulas = pd.DataFrame(list(sht.range(r).formula))
formulas.index = df.index
formulas.columns = df.columns

df = df.combine_first(formulas)
sht.range(r).options(index=False, header=False).value = df
```

By doing this the live excel formula are not overwritten by their values:

```
       A         B         C         D
0.351741  Excel B1  0.238705  Excel D1
0.950817  0.665594  0.671151  Excel D2
Excel A3  0.442725  0.658816  Excel D3
0.155604  0.567044  Excel C4  0.666576
Excel A5  0.751562  Excel C5  0.597252
0.577770  Excel B6  Excel C6  0.123392
```